# Should i use a try catch statement for reading a configparser file when loading a setting?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that tries to read a config and if fails, creates a new one and writes to the file "settings.ini". This feels really chunky and not particularly concise. Is this the supposed way of reading a configparser file?

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
def getSettings(self):
    try:
        with open('settings.ini') as f:
            return config.read_file(f)

    except:
        config['DEFAULT'] = {'Host': '127.0.0.1',
                             'Port': '5822'}
        return config['DEFAULT']
```

Comment: I think admins will remove the question; it doesn't seem belong here. Meanwhile this is your app and your decision, but: 1) it will be very strange to have overwritten config after reading attempt, even if it was wrong; 2) there can be other exceptions, not only IOError; 3) second reading may fail as well. 
So just write an error into log and return default config if reading failed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice; it's quite an hassle trying out new things. I will just stick with json file I guess.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the question

Comment: Other than - you need to include your definition of `config`

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: If the code is working then the question is on topic as long as the definition of config is added and the title is modified as @TobySpeight indicated.

Comment: Thank you all. What exactly is the "definition of config" mentioned above?

Comment: Now you have removed even more code, while there was already not enough for a review. The definition of config is where you define the configuration. What does the configuration look like? Just copy the configuration file into the question, after stripping it from sensitive data like passwords and API keys, and please provide a usage example. How are you actually using this code in your application? If there's no application yet, it's too early in the process for a review.